# Virtual Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I would like to manage subdomains exclusively through .htaccess.

I am able to catch subdomains that I set up - for example, support.testsite.com - currently, I redirect that to testsite.com/support.

What I would like to do is retain the subdomain, even after the redirect - so support.testsite.com seems to stay in the address bar for the user, even though it is actually located at testsite.com/support.

Should I maintain another .htaccess file in /support that rewrites the address?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a potential question for Server Fault

Comment: This sounds like a job for mod_rewrite!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) in the virtual domain support.testsite.com.

Load following modules into your apache: `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_http`

```
ProxyPass / http://testsite.com/support/
<Location />
  ProxyPass / https://testsite.com/support/
</Location>
```

Just a warning: expect some fiddling around making your application work correctly behind reverse proxy - some more reading can be found on [mod_proxy_html apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) and [mod_proxy_html homepage](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/).